# Reshape the wide format to long format keeping a column constant

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe, which has student name, their marks in Maths & Science in months from 1 to 6 and passing marks for each student in each month. Sample of the dataframe is -

```
Name  2023_01_Maths  2023_02_Maths  2023_03_Maths  2023_04_Maths  2023_05_Maths  2023_06_Maths  2023_01_Science  2023_02_Science  2023_03_Science  2023_04_Science  2023_05_Science  2023_06_Science  2023_07_Science  2023_01_Passing_marks  2023_02_Passing_marks  2023_03_Passing_marks  2023_04_Passing_marks  2023_05_Passing_marks  2023_06_Passing_marks
A              4              3             10              9              9              7                3                0                1               10                1                2                6                      4                      2                      9                      8                      3                      0
B              5              7              4              4              6              1                3                7                8                2                3                4                3                      5                      1                      4                      6                      5                     10
C              3              8              9              1             10              1                0                4                7                5                8                0               10                      2                      8                      8                      8                     10                      6
D              6              4              6              9              3              0               10                1                0                7                5                8                5                      4                      9                      6                      4                      0                      8
E              7              3              5              5              6             10                0                2               10                7               10                3                8                      1                      1                      0                      9                     10                      5
F              8              2              7              6              8              4                4                0                4                9                8                1                6                      7                      7                      4                      8                      1                      6
G              4              6              8              8              6              6                0                2                2               10                8               10                5                      9                      2                      6                      5                      3                      6
H              3              4              0              1              0              6               10                6                7               10                1                5                5                      5                      5                      3                      6                      4                      6
I              2              3              3              9              9             10               10                4                3                9                9                8                4                      1                      5                      1                      3                      2                      4
J              0              2              2              2              3              8                6                6                3                9               10                3                1                      9                      3                      6                      1                      0                      9'
```

I want to transform this dataframe into long format. like

```
Name  Year month Subject Marks Passing_marks
 A    2023  01    Maths   4       4
 A    2023  01    Science 3       4
 B    2023  01    Maths   5       5
 B    2023  01    Science 3       5
```

I tried the following code,

```
df_subjects = df.set_index(['Name])[['2023_01_Maths' , '2023_02_Maths' , '2023_03_Maths' , '2023_04_Maths' , '2023_05_Maths'  ,'2023_06_Maths' , '2023_01_Science' , '2023_02_Science',  2023_03_Science'  ,'2023_04_Science',  '2023_05_Science'  ,'2023_06_Science' , '2023_07_Science']]
df_passing_marks = df.set_index(['Name'])[['2023_01_Passing_marks',  '2023_02_Passing_marks',  '2023_03_Passing_marks',  '2023_04_Passing_marks',  '2023_05_Passing_marks',  '2023_06_Passing_marks']]

df_subject.columns = df_subject.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
df_subject = df_subject.stack([0, 1, 2]).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Marks'})

df_passing_marks.columns = df_passing_marks.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
df_passing_marks = df_passing_marks.stack([0, 1, 2]).reset_index().rename(columns={'marks': 'Passing_marks'})
```

Now, I'm merging these two dataframe to get required format.

```
df_subject.merge(df_passing_marks[['Name', 'level_1', 'level_2', 'Passing_marks']], on=["Name", 'level_1', 'level_2'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a good use case for `janitor`'s [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

out = (df
   .pivot_longer(index='Name',
                 names_pattern = r'(\d{4})_(\d+)_(.*)',
                 names_to=('Year', 'month', '.value'))
   .melt(['Name', 'Year', 'month', 'Passing_marks'],
         var_name='Subject', value_name='marks')
)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Year month Passing_marks  Subject  marks
0      A  2023    01             4    Maths    4.0
1      B  2023    01             5    Maths    5.0
2      C  2023    01             2    Maths    3.0
3      D  2023    01             4    Maths    6.0
4      E  2023    01             1    Maths    7.0
..   ...   ...   ...           ...      ...    ...
135    F  2023    07           NaN  Science    6.0
136    G  2023    07           NaN  Science    5.0
137    H  2023    07           NaN  Science    5.0
138    I  2023    07           NaN  Science    4.0
139    J  2023    07           NaN  Science    1.0

[140 rows x 6 columns]
```

Other approach with classical reshaping, here using a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
out = (df
   .set_index('Name')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('_', n=2, expand=True), axis=1))
   .rename_axis(columns=['Year', 'month', 'Subject'])
   .stack([0, 1])
   .melt('Passing_marks', value_name='Marks', ignore_index=False)
   .reset_index().astype({'Year': int, 'month': int})
)
```

Comment: is there any possibility to do this w/o Janitor?

Comment: Yes of course (have you tested @Mark's answer?), but janitor is easy to install and quite powerful ;)

Comment: See update for another approach

Comment: @mozway do you ever use R? I'm surprised considering your amazing-ness with Pandas that I haven't seen any tidyverse answers by you on here 

Comment: @Mark not anymore and I think I probably forgot everything ;)

Comment: oh well more questions for me 

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of getting the desired output:

```
# make the data long
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Name"], var_name="Year", value_name="Score")    

# separate the melted column names into Year, Month and Subject columns
df[["Year", "Month", "Subject"]] = df['Year'].str.extract(r"(?P<Year>\d{4})_(?P<Month>\d{2})_(?P<Subject>.*)", expand=True)

# pivot it wider again, then melt only the passing marks column
(df.pivot(index=["Name", "Year", "Month"], columns="Subject", values="Score")
  .melt(['Passing_marks'], var_name="Subject", value_name="Score", ignore_index= False).fillna(0))

# Output:
                 Passing_marks  Subject  Score
Name Year Month                               
A    2023 01               4.0    Maths    4.0
          02               2.0    Maths    3.0
          03               9.0    Maths   10.0
          04               8.0    Maths    9.0
          05               3.0    Maths    9.0
...                        ...      ...    ...
J    2023 03               6.0  Science    3.0
          04               1.0  Science    9.0
          05               0.0  Science   10.0
          06               9.0  Science    3.0
          07               0.0  Science    1.0

[140 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is to split into two dataframes, one that contains the subjects, another the passing marks. Reshape the dataframes and merge on the common columns:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = df.set_index('Name')

subjects = [col for col in df if not col.endswith('marks')]

subjects = df.loc[:, subjects]

marks = [col for col in df if col.endswith('marks')]

marks = df.loc[:, marks]

subjects = (subjects
           .pivot_longer(ignore_index=False,
                         names_to = ('year','month','subject'), 
                         names_sep='_', 
                         values_to='marks')
          )
marks = (marks
         # named regex groups are now supported
         # for `.value`, use `_` as group name
         .pivot_longer(ignore_index=False, 
                       names_pattern = r"(?P<year>\d+)_(?P<month>\d+)_(?P<_>.+)")
       )

subjects.merge(marks, on = ['Name', 'year', 'month'])

      year month  subject  marks  Passing_marks
Name
A     2023    01    Maths      4              4
A     2023    01  Science      3              4
B     2023    01    Maths      5              5
B     2023    01  Science      3              5
C     2023    01    Maths      3              2
...    ...   ...      ...    ...            ...
H     2023    06  Science      5              6
I     2023    06    Maths     10              4
I     2023    06  Science      8              4
J     2023    06    Maths      8              9
J     2023    06  Science      3              9

[120 rows x 5 columns]
```

Using the same concept, but without [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
df = df.set_index('Name')

subjects = [col for col in df if not col.endswith('marks')]

subjects = df.loc[:, subjects]

marks = [col for col in df if col.endswith('marks')]

marks = df.loc[:, marks]

subjects.columns = subjects.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)

subjects.columns.names = ['year', 'month', 'subject']

subjects = subjects.stack(['year', 'month', 'subject']).rename('marks')

marks.columns = marks.columns.str.split('_', n = 2, expand=True)

marks.columns.names = ['year', 'month', None]

marks = marks.stack(['year', 'month'])

pd.DataFrame.merge(subjects, marks, on = ['Name','year','month'])

                 marks  Passing_marks
Name year month
A    2023 01       4.0              4
          01       3.0              4
          02       3.0              2
          02       0.0              2
          03      10.0              9
...                ...            ...
J    2023 04       9.0              1
          05       3.0              0
          05      10.0              0
          06       8.0              9
          06       3.0              9

[120 rows x 2 columns]
```